# Removing application from IIS 6

Tags: iis, web-server, iis-6

I have an iis 6 server that someone else used before and there are a few applications in the defaultAppPool. I would like to be able to only keep the default application.

How can I remove an application from an application pool?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move them, and not just delete the applications, you'll need to create another application pool if you don't have one: Open IIS Manager, right click application pools, New, Application Pool.

Then go the application you want to move out of the default app pool, right click properties, go the the Home Directory Tab, and select the new/different application pool.

Simple as that.

FYI, it'll kill any sessions in that application when you move it.

Comment: Thanks for that, could be useful. However, what I want to do is really removing the apps

Comment: Unless I am missing something, you can just delete them out of II6? If someone deleted the files, and not the app through IIS, you can use the meta explorer to find them... http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56fc92ee-a71a-4c73-b628-ade629c89499&DisplayLang=en

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the folders back to the drive with the same paths and names. They can be empty. Then refresh IIS and the applications should show there again. Delete the applications in IIS, then you can delete the folders again. Refresh IIS and they should be gone.